# many to one relationship and accessing max value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel tables.  Spreadsheet A contains a list of salespeople.  Spreadsheet B contains the items the salesperson has sold along with a date and quantity sold.

So that sets up the one to many relationship.

The trick now what I want to do is to populate Spreadsheet A based on the salesperson's name in Both Spreadsheet A and B - and I want to find the max date (as in the most recent date) and then the corresponding dollar amount sold for that day.

The vlookup function works great to find the correct salesperson, but does not return the max date - there I found power pivot, but the trouble with power pivot and pivot tables in general is that I have no clue about how to just return the value that corresponds with the max date.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution that will work for your needs

1)To find the Max Date of a Sales person you can use the "Aggregate" function for excel 2010.

> =AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$2:$A$10/($B$2:$B$10=F2),1)

Here is  a break down of the formula

> =AGGREGATE(
>
> ```
> 14 = Large,
>
> 6 = Ignore Error Values,
> ```
>
> Date Range / (Criteria Range = Criteria),
>
> 1 = Find first Large number )

also this is a great video to watch to get a better understanding of how the formula works
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2XCI8Gvz9k

2) Number sold of that date.

Now that you know the Max date and sales person all you need is a simple "SUMIFS(" to find out how many they sold on that date

> =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$10,$B$2:$B$10,F2,$A$2:$A$10,G2)

This will also cater if you have a duplicate sales person on the same date.

The other advantage to these formula is that you won't need to continue re-filtering your data table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use two formulas.

For last date per name use

```
=MAX(IF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$25=Sheet1!$A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$25,0))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>Enter</kbd>

For sales per person on person's max date use a lookup that combines date and name as the lookup value.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$25,MATCH(Sheet1!B2&Sheet1!A2,INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$25&Sheet2!$B$2:$B$25,0),0))
```

Here is a screenshot of Sheet1 with Sheet2 super-imposed
[image]